# Logout functionality For Zendesk in Pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cookies, session-variables

I want to implement a logout function.  When a user clicks `Logout`, I want to end their session and redirect to another page.  Sadly, I am limited to only JavaScript.

**EDIT:**
Moving this over to Zendesk because it seems like they have a Remote Authentication API.

Thank you to all the people who answered.

Comment: Do the correct methods already exist on the server?

Comment: @slandau I have no access to the server at all, which is why I can only use javascript

Comment: @slandau has a good question, so do you actually know _what_ server technology it is using? These normally have common methods for logging out and you could simply access them via JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what server technology you're using.

Let's say there's a **logout.aspx** page.  You could just do an AJAX request to that page to *zap* the session, or delete a cookie that the application might be using to cache authentication, then redirect like so:

`window.location = "http://www.mysite.com/logout.aspx";`

**UPDATE**

I just found this post on SO that should help (that wasn't easy):
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237476/zendesk-remote-auth-using-java

Comment: I have no access to the server so I can only use javascript

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your login session state is stored in a cookie that isn't [`httpOnly`](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly), you can simply delete the login cookie by setting its expiry date to a the past.  For example, using [this cookie library](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie):

```
$.cookie('login_cookie_name', null);
```

Then you can just do a `location.assign('/logged_out_page.html');` to redirect to another page.

Comment: (I won't -1) but there is no mention as of yet of jQuery. However, that is a good plug-in. I use it also.

Comment: @pixelbobby: Despite its name, that plugin doesn't actually require jQuery. If you're not using jQuery, rename the namespace on [line 60](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/jquery.cookie.js#L60) (you could even just change it to `window`) and remove [line 64](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/jquery.cookie.js#L64).

Comment: Zendesk session cookie is HttpOnly, you can't access it using js.